# How to set a variable value to zero each row

Tags: mysql, variables

Data of table_1 as text:

id,col_1,col_2

1,10,6

2,3,21

3,44,3

4,24,17

5,39,42

Primary key: id

Database version: 8.0.19

I need your help to set the variable @col value to zero each row, so that the final result is:

id,c1,c2

1,10,16

2,3,24

3,44,47

4,24,41

5,39,81

```
SET @col := 0;
SELECT id, (@col := @col + col_1) AS c1, (@col := @col + col_2) AS c2 FROM table_1 ORDER BY id;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no idea why you would need a variable c1 = col1 and c2 = col1+col2

Comment: Unless this is homework for variables, you are over-complicating the problem. It is as simple as this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7BrnAu2596ADCgWYenZNS/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a column with @col := 0 in front of the computation

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_1  (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `col_1` INTEGER,
  `col_2` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table_1 
  (`id`, `col_1`, `col_2`)
VALUES
  ('1', '10', '6'),
  ('2', '3', '21'),
  ('3', '44', '3'),
  ('4', '24', '17'),
  ('5', '39', '42');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SET @col := 0;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT id,@col := 0, (@col := @col + col_1) AS c1, (@col := @col + col_2) AS c2 FROM table_1 ORDER BY id;

| id  | @col := 0 | c1  | c2  |
| --- | --------- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 0         | 10  | 16  |
| 2   | 0         | 3   | 24  |
| 3   | 0         | 44  | 47  |
| 4   | 0         | 24  | 41  |
| 5   | 0         | 39  | 81  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Why does my answer work 
MySQL actually loops from row number 1 and then starts from the left column in the select statement to the right.

So that the order of the column decides what is in the user defined variable.

You can build very cool algorithms with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to declare a variable to achieve the output.
Try This :

```
SELECT id, col_1 AS c1, (col_1+ col_2) AS c2 FROM table_1 ORDER BY id;
```

you will get the desired output.

In MySql Variable is required only when there is a need to pick data from another location/row. For current row operations, all column value can be used directly to perform any operation related to that row.

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. In this case I really need to use a variable. Otherwise, I would certainly run this code.